# global_asax does not exist in the namespace ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, global-asax

hi i added a class file to global.asax..

Code inside global_asax :

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeFile="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global" %>
```

Code inside global.asax.cs:

```
public partial class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{}
```

but still i get the above Error:

> The type or namespace name 'global_asax' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

here is the namespace ASP code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ASP
{
[CompilerGlobalScope]
public class global_asax :HttpApplication
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public global_asax();
}
}
```

here global_asax is inheriting HttpApplication..how do i change this file and make it inherit Global Class

Answer (score 0):

open Visual studio 2010 once its loaded

```
open explorer -> goto > C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0
```

copy the required System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll into your project "References" folder select that reference and under properties set "copy local" to true and once you publish it will be in your bin folder and wont impact at all on any server be it x32 or x64.

Answer (score 0):

Are your files *really* called `global_asax` and `global_asax.cs`? Not `global.asax` and `global.asax.cs`?

Normally, `global.asax` would reference the `Global` class in the namespace of your project, like so:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

And `global.asax.cs` would be thus namespaced:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
    }
}
```